# Using database name along with service name while importing from Oracle using Sqoop

Tags: sqoop

When importing from oracle using SQOOP ,have already specified the service name 
in the connection string  `jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername/servicename` and unable to add the databasename in the connection string and also not able to specify the same in the --table parameter as databasename.tablename, getting the below error.

> Import failed: There is no column found in the target table
>   databasename.tablename. Please ensure that your table name is correct.

Is there any way to use it or using the --query parameter is the only option.

Comment: Can you post your Sqoop command?

Answer (score 0):

The correct working command with Oracle

`sqoop import  --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/service_name" --query "select column_name from oracle_schema_name.table where $CONDITIONS" --username $USER_NAME --password $PASSWORD --target-dir $TABLE_DIRECTORY_NAME`

Comment: yes,with query option it would work fine but just wanted to check if we can achieve the same using just the --table parameter.

Comment: There is an issue with table parameter in Oracle. It may work with some version and may not work with some version.